# Correct usage of arrayfun/bsxfun in Matlab - simple example

Tags: arrays, matlab, bsxfun, simplification

Assume we have a 1-d Matrix, with random length:

```
M = [102,4,12,6,8,3,4,65,23,43,111,4]
```

Moreover I have a vector with values that are linked to the index of M:

```
V = [1,5]
```

What i want is a simple code of:

```
counter = 1;
NewM = zeros(length(V)*3,1);
for i = 1:length(V)
    NewM(counter:(counter+2)) = M(V(i):(V(i)+2))
    counter = counter+3;
end
```

So, the result will be

```
NewM = [102,4,12,8,3,4]
```

In other words, I want the V to V+2 values from M in a new array.
I'm pretty sure this can be done easier, but I'm struggeling with how to implement it in arrayfun /bsxfun...

```
bsxfun(@(x,y) x(y:(y+2)),M,V)
```

Comment: Never throw `bsxfun` (makes things faster!) and `arrayfun`/`cellfun` (just makes them easier...) into the same pot, the latter internally uses loops and you should always preferably use `bsxfun` if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bsxfun` it's about getting the V<sub>i</sub> on one dimension and the +0, +1 +2 on the other:

```
M = [102,4,12,6,8,3,4,65,23,43,111,4];
V = [1,5];
NewM = M( bsxfun(@plus, V(:), 0:2) )

NewM =
    102     4    12       
      8     3     4
```

Or if you want a line:

```
NewM = reshape(NewM.', 1, [])

NewM =
    102     4    12     8     3     4
```

Comment: though i should avoid this comment according to stackoverflow: thanks alot!

Comment: @Jonas I could add to this answer that the `reshape` can wrap the `bsxfun` to reduce the `NewM` rows vector computation to a single line:  `NewM = M(reshape(bsxfun(@plus, V(:), 0:2),1,[]))`

Answer (score 2):

Using `arrayfun` (note that `M` is used as an *"external"* matrix entity in this scope, whereas the `arrayfun` anonymous function parameter `x` correspond to the elements in `V`)

```
NewM = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) M(x:x+2), V, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

With result

```
NewM =

   102     4    12     8     3     4
```

Answer (score 1):

One fully vectorized solution is to expand `V` to create the correct indexing vector. In your case:

```
[1,2,3,5,6,7]
```

You can expand `V` to replicate each of it's elements `n` times and then add a repeating vector of `0:(n-1)`:

```
n = 3;
idx = kron(V, ones(1,n)) + mod(0:numel(V)*n-1,n)
```

So here `kron(V, ones(1,n))` will return `[1,1,1,5,5,5]` and `mod(0:numel(V)*n-1,n)` will return `[0,1,2,0,1,2]` which add up to the required indexing vector `[1,2,3,5,6,7]`

and now it's just

```
M(idx)
```

Note a slightly faster alternative to `kron` is `reshape(repmat(V,n,1),1,[])`